# arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 010416: Error in setting raster table filter for raster. Failed to execute (Con)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, con, error-010416

I am having trouble figuring out which `Con()` statement is the correct one, or if my renaming is incorrect.

Full code below

```
# Name: Ortho4Calculator.py
# Description: Performs map algebra on individual bands and composites them back together
# Requirements: Spatial Analyst Extension

# Import arcpy & os
import os
import arcpy

# Import spatial analyst extension
from ExtractData import LicenseError
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Check out Spatial Analyst extension
try:
    if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
        print ("Checked out \"Spatial\" Extension")
    else:
        raise LicenseError
except LicenseError:
    print "Spatial Analyst license is unavailable"
except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)

# Set workspace as parameter
arcpy.env.workspace = (r"C:\ProjectData")
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = (r"C:\ProjectData\temp")

# overwrite files with the same name
env.overwriteOutput = True

# Get raster list
raster_List = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
for raster in raster_List:
    print(raster)
    # raster_List.getRasterBands()

# Create for loop to iterate over raster names to create individual bands
for raster in raster_List:
    BaseName = raster
    print(BaseName) #correct
    band1 = os.path.join(raster, "Band_1")
    band2 = os.path.join(raster, "Band_2")
    band3 = os.path.join(raster, "Band_3")
    band4 = os.path.join(raster, "Band_4")
    print(band1) #corrrect

    # Create empty list for bands
    bandList = []

    # Raster Calculations
    #rasBand1 = Con((band1 == 0) & (band2 == 0) & (band3 == 0) & (band4 > 0), 1, band1)
    rasBand1 = Con(band1, 1, band1, (band1 == 0) & (band2 == 0) & (band3 == 0) & (band4 > 0))
    rasBand2 = Con(((band1 == 0) & (band2 == 0) & (band3 == 0) & (band4 > 0)), 1, band2)
    rasBand3 = Con(((band1 == 0) & (band2 == 0) & (band3 == 0) & (band4 > 0)), 1, band3)
    rasBand4 = os.path.join(raster, "Band_4")

    #arcpy.CopyRaster_management(raster, r"C:\Project Data")
    arcpy.Rename_management(rasBand1, raster + "Band_1")
    bandList.append(rasBand1)
    arcpy.Rename_management(rasBand2, raster + "Band_2")
    bandList.append(rasBand2)
    arcpy.Rename_management(rasBand3, raster + "Band_3")
    bandList.append(rasBand3)
    arcpy.Rename_management(rasBand4, raster + "Band_4")
    bandList.append(rasBand4)
    print(bandList) #bands not renamed correctly
```

When I try the first way (#rasBand1) it gives an error

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\python.exe C:/GISCustomization/FinalProject/Ortho4Calculator.py
Checked out "Spatial" Extension
a10seg595970.tif
a10seg595970.tif
a10seg595970.tif\Band_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/GISCustomization/FinalProject/Ortho4Calculator.py", line 60, in <module>
    arcpy.Rename_management(rasBand1, raster + "Band_1")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 4528, in Rename
    raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (Rename).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I try the second way (rasBand1) it gives an error

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\python.exe C:/GISCustomization/FinalProject/Ortho4Calculator.py
Checked out "Spatial" Extension
a10seg595970.tif
a10seg595970.tif
a10seg595970.tif\Band_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/GISCustomization/FinalProject/Ortho4Calculator.py", line 54, in <module>
    rasBand1 = Con(band1, 1, band1, (band1 == 0) & (band2 == 0) & (band3 == 0) & (band4 > 0))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 269, in Con
    where_clause)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 263, in Wrapper
    where_clause)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 510, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 010416: Error in setting raster table filter for raster.
Failed to execute (Con).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't rename a band, it's part of a (file/database/object) raster not a raster in itself, you can copy a band as a new file though, that makes it a new raster in its own right.

According to the [help for Con](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) the where_clause should be surrounded in quotes though that's not the only problem here. According to the [SQL syntax reference](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000033000000) the *and* is `and` not `&` or `&&` - that's raster calculator syntax and should go into the first clause and not the 4th so your Con statement should be more like `rasBand1 = Con((band1 == 0) & (band2 == 0) & (band3 == 0) & (band4 > 0), 1, band1)` but that will create a raster full of 0's and 1's as the result is 0 if all the bands are 0 and 1 if any of the bands are not 0 - perhaps that's what you're after... though that conflicts with your original statement `rasBand1 = Con(band1, 1, band1, (band1 == 0) & (band2 == 0) & (band3 == 0) & (band4 > 0))` which will produce a raster if 0 where band1 is 0 and nodata for any nonzero value in any of band 1 to 4 - even if the SQL was corrected.

[Cell statistics](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000) might be of use here to compound the bands into a single raster which makes the Con run faster, as it stands each equality is created as a binary raster object then each `&` is evaluated which is tediously slow, cell statistics is one operation performed by an executable which would reduce the conditional temporary rasters as python objects. Your code would then look like `rasBand1 = Con(CellStatistics([band1,band2,band3,band4],"maximum") == 0,1,band1)` which would run much faster.